# No access on attributes of abstract class objects in subclass methods in java

Tags: java, algorithm, abstract-class

I want to write some different algorithms for different data structures(e.g. tree, list, array, ...). The methods of the data structures are 90% identical except for the method parameter.

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> {
    public T key;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild;

    public boolean find(BinaryTreeNode<T> root, T key) { /* implementation */ }
}

public class ListItem<T> {
    public T key;
    public ListItem<T> next;

    public boolean find(ListItem<T> root, T key) { /* implementation */ }
}
```

In order not to have to write each method individually I made an abstract `DataStruct<T>` class

```
public abstract class DataStruct<T> {
    /**
    * finds the key in dataStruct
    * @param dataStruct DataStruct to look for key
    * @param key value of type T to find in dataStruct
    * @return true if key is in dataStruct else false
    */
    public abstract find(DataStruct<T> dataStruct, T key);
}
```

I let `BinaryTreeNode<T>` and `ListItem<T>` `extend` `DataStruct<T>`

Now my problem is to access the class attributes. I solved it like this:

```
public class ListItem<T> extends DataStruct<T> {
    public T key;
    public ListItem<T> next;

    @Override
    public boolean find(DataStruct<T> listItem, T key) {
        ListItem<T> tmpListItem = (ListItem<T>) listItem;
        while(tmpListItem.next != null) {
            if(tmpListItem.key == key)
               return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not feel well coded because I had to create a temporary `ListItem<T>` to cast the `DataStruct<T>` to access the class attributes of `ListItem<T>`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why does the `find` method of `ListItem` require a `DataStruct<T> listItem` argument? Shouldn't it perform the search on itself (i.e. `this`)?

Comment: Was some precondition from above (exercise sheet). To implement the method `find` with return type `boolean` and those two parameters. Maybe its not the "best practice" to do it like this. After I have thought about your comment more closely I have recognized that the `DataStruct<T>` parameter was really superfluous. Working with `this` solves all the problems I had.

Comment: (Prefer `interface` over `class` for interface definition.) (Not defining a `find()` but `Map.get()` and `List.indexOf()` is one of the peeves I have with the Java Collections Framework.) Please add [doc comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide).

Comment: So an `interface` is better because I do not implement any methods? But I still need a superclass like `DataStruct<T>`, right? I do not understand your second sentence. What do you mean by it? Also added some JavaDoc to the `find` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `find` method is not a `static` method, it doesn't make sense that it accepts a `DataStruct<T>` object and performs the search on that object. It makes more sense to perform the search on itself, which eliminates the need to cast anything:

```
public boolean find(T key) {
    ListItem<T> tmpListItem = this;
    while(tmpListItem.next != null) {
        if(tmpListItem.key.equals(key))
           return true;
        tmpListItem = tmpListItem.next;
    }
}
```

Now, it some of your methods do require a `DataStruct<T>` argument, and you require, for example, that the implementation of these methods in `ListItem` accpet only a `ListItem`, it will make sense to check the type of the input argument, throw an exception (or return false, or whatever makes sense) if the run-type is wrong, and perform the cast. This is a common practice in methods such as `equals`, which accept an `Object` and usually require that the run-time type be a specific type.

For example:

```
public boolean find(DataStruct<T> listItem, T key) {
    if (!(listItem instanceof ListItem)) {
        // decide whether to return false or throw an exception
    }
    ListItem<T> tmpListItem = (ListItem<T>) listItem;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That has answered even my original question. Many thanks for the answer/help.